# Replace a value based on conditions of two rows VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with more than 30,000 entries. I am interested in row D and row F. They have 3 combination of values based on row D and row F

```
   A           B      C          D          E       F  
10/11/2016    501    General     2          1     1795 to 2395
10/11/2016    502    Public    1 to 2       1     675 to 750
10/11/2016    503    Public    1 to 3       1     1450
```

Expected Result

```
A              B      C          D          E       F  
10/11/2016    501    General     2          1     1795 to 2395
10/11/2016    502    Public    1 to 2       1     675 to 750
10/11/2016    503    Public      1          1     1450
```

What I am trying to achieve is:
replace "to and anything after to" [column D] when there is no "to"(range) [column F]

The code I have tried but did not get the desired result:

```
Sub RemoveAfterTo()


    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

For i = Last To 1 Step -1
     If (Cells(i, "D").Value) Like "*to*" And (Cells(i, "F").Value) <> "*to*"
     Then

         Cells(i, "D").Replace What:="to*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart

    End If

  Next i

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<>` can't be used with wild cards. Replace  the condition `(Cells(i, "F").Value) <> "*to*"`

by the condition `Not (Cells(i, "F").Value Like "*to*")`

This yields (after fixing the misplaced `Then` and declaring variables as per good practice):

```
Sub RemoveAfterTo()
    Dim Last As Long, i As Long

    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "D").Value) Like "*to*" And Not (Cells(i, "F").Value Like "*to*") Then
            Cells(i, "D").Replace What:="to*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Which works as intended with your sample data.

Comment: It Works! Thanks for correcting and putting some light on how <> works with wildcards. :)